# Losing STDOUT when using Open3.capture3 and rake?

Tags: ruby, windows, rake, popen3

A build system that I use at work invokes several external console applications, Node.js among others.

The issue I am seeing is the STDOUT channel seems to not work after `Open3.capture3` is invoked. For instance, I have a task called `compileLess`:

```
desc "Compile LESS"
task :compileLess do
   puts "Preparing to compile LESS..."
   execute "recess less/bootstrap.less --compress > output/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   puts "Finished compiling LESS"
end


def execute(cmdLine, print_stdout = false)
   puts "Executing #{cmdLine}"
   stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(cmdLine)
   puts stdout if print_stdout
   return stdout, stderr, status
end
```

What I would expect to see is something like:

```
Preparing to compile LESS...
Executing recess less/bootstrap.less --compress > output/css/bootstrap.min.css
Finished compiling LESS
```

But anything after the invocation of `Open3.capture3` disables `puts` and `print`. I can force them to work by explicitly using:

```
STDOUT.puts "goodbye world"
```

I just want to know why it doesn't work.

Specs:

- Window 7 Professional 32 bit
- Ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
- Rake, version 10.1.0
- Node v0.10.22

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: I mentioned what I get in the question, but to reiterate, any puts or prints after the open3 capture doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: smells like a bug, I'd report it http://bugs.ruby-lang.org

Answer (score 1):

You redirected the STDOUT of the command-line with `> output/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Your STDOUT from `capture3()` is empty of course.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how I can write the css to disk without losing STDOUT?

Comment: @MattSaw How about " | tee output/css/bootstrap.min.css" instead of " > output/css/bootstrap.min.css"? Not sure if it's what you wanted.